# How can I Upload multiple files from different folders in shiny web app?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to upload multiple files from different folders from my computer. I have tried with:

```
  fileInput(...,multiple=TRUE)
```

But this only allows me to upload the files that I have selected using CTRL, I can not navigate throught folders and select different files or droping then to the button directly.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess would be that this is not a shiny, but rather OS limitation.